# How can I shuffle list of lists with actually shuffling all elements?

Tags: python, nested-lists, shuffle, playing-cards

```
import random
row = ['\u2665', '\u2663', '\u2666', '\u2660']  # ["Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"]
symbol = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
level = input('Choose Difficulty level: Easy (1), Medium (2), Hard (3): ')
while level!="1" and level!="2" and level!="3":
   level = (input('Choose Difficulty level: Easy (1), Medium (2), Hard (3): '))
if level == "1":
   col=4
elif level== "2":
   col=10
else:
   col=1

def value(symbol):
  if symbol=="A":
    return 1
  elif symbol=="Q" or symbol=="J" or symbol=="K":
    return 10
  else:
    return int(symbol)

deck =[]
for i in range(len(row)):
  deck.append([])
  for j in range(col):
     card = [symbol[j], row[i], value(symbol[j]), str(symbol[j])+str(row[i]) , False]
     deck.append(card)
```

I have this code and I want to shuffle the list deck.

But the function `shuffle.random(deck)` only shuffles the 4 rows...

I thought about creating a new list with only the cards and shuffle that but then I don't know how to make it a list with 4 rows and 4 or 10 or 13 columns.

Any ideas and suggestions would be valuable !

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Comment: Simple: you `random.shuffle()` every list in the list, then you shuffle the list.

Comment: @KlausD. It is no that simple, if you do it like this then you only changed the order of the cards and the rows. I want to have for example a Spade, a Club, a Diamond and a Heart at the same row

Comment: ask yourself whether `deck` should be list of lists in the first place.  Make changes to the overall design.

Comment: @buran What do you suggest for a game of cards where the player will give the collumn and the row of the card ?

Comment: I don't know what is the game that you implement. The resulting `deck` does not make much sense - some elements are empty list, then rest elements are heterogeneous lists like this -  `['A', '♥', 1, 'A♥', False]`. I doubt it is what you expect either. What is the purpose of shuffling the elements in the nested lists? What is the purpose of the deck in the game, etc. Print the resulting deck for yourself before you try to shuffle it.

Comment: @buran I changed the list and now its ok. The exercise requires from me to shufle the cards ( the list  ['A', '♥', 1, 'A♥', False] ) and then play thegame. Then the game requires 2 inpurs from the player, 1 for row and 1 for column to pick a card. Don't you think that I have ti make a list of 4 lists of 4 or 10 or 13 elements each ?

Comment: please, if you changed your code - update the snippet in your question. so basically you now claim to have list of lists of lists. Make a `deck` of all cards, take a random sample of n cards (as much as you need). Do you need to put these n cards in some sort of nested data structure is up to you and also depends on what you will do next. You can find the index of the card with pure calculations from user input for row and column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.shuffle(inp)`

Create a recursive function: If `input` is `list` shuffle it, else, leave it

Since lists are mutable everything is in-place

No matter how nested your lists are, everything will be shuffled

```
import random
inp_list = [1, [2,3,4, [5,6,7], 8, 9], [10, 11]]
def shuffle_list(inp):
    if type(inp) is list:
        random.shuffle(inp)
        for i in inp:
            shuffle_list(i)
shuffle_list(inp_list)
print(inp_list)
```

```
[1, [11, 10], [8, [7, 5, 6], 9, 3, 2, 4]]
```